# how to add a script inside multiple div classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i have a `javascript` code and i want to print it inside different `div`'s.

example:

```
<div class='block output-1'>...</div>
<div class='block output-2'>...</div>
<div class='block output-3'>...</div>
```

and i want to replace every `div` containers that have `.block` class with the below `<script>` code

```
<script>document.write('text');</script>
```

i tried by `Jquery` and i could make it  : http://jsbin.com/yokipajiho/1/edit?html,js,output

but i hope if there is any better or different way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. The JSBin code didn't seem to have anything to with the code posted here.

Comment: You don't want to use `document.write()` after the page is loaded, as it will overwrite the entire page. It should generally be avoided these days, but if used it should only be used in code that runs inline during loading. If you want to modify a DIV, assign to its `innerHTML`.

Comment: what i want to do is i wrote a `javascript` code that generates blogger posts and i want to make it appear in different places and each one will generate the posts based on a specific label i will assign later, so i need the `script` to output in different `div's`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write`, assign to the `innerHTML` property of the DIVs.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".block").forEach((div, index) => div.innerHTML = "text " + index);
```

```html
<div class='block output-1'>...</div>
<div class='block output-2'>...</div>
<div class='block output-3'>...</div>
```

Comment: okay, but i don't wanna use just a simple `document.write` code i have a very long `code` which generate posts from a `file.xml` will it work on it with no problems ?

Comment: I don't see why not. It doesn't matter where the text comes from, you just assign it to `innerHTML` (or `textContent` if you don't want HTML tags to be processed). This should be explained in any JavaScript tutorial.